# AngularJS ng-repeat in two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to use ng-repeat inside div like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="image in HomeCtrl.images.data" >
    <a ng-href="@{{ image.code }}"><img ng-src="@{{ image.url }}" ></a>
</li>
```

Here is images array :

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": [
      "https://url1.com",
      "https://url2.com"
    ],
    "code": [
      "3cs14vs4",
      "512631va"
    ]
  }
}
```

**images array is inside HomeCtrl**

Comment: So what is the problem, it doesnt work? Are you getting error?

Comment: I am not getting expected results , it shows the entire code array in **ng-src** , same for url

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in a view that is already assigned to the controller, 
If your in a different controller you can do something like that:

```
<ul ng-conroller="HomeCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="image in images.data.url track by $index" >
    <a ng-href="{{ images.data.code[$index] }}">
       <img ng-src="{{ image.data.url[$index] }}" >
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

- Keep in mind that the order of the element should be in sync

---

Aside from your question I think a better data structure should be as following:

```
{
 {"code": "xx", "url": "yyy"},
 {"code": "xx", "url": "yyy"},
 {"code": "xx", "url": "yyy"},
 ....
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, I should use this data structure to get this code working . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please find following working snippet.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    //Change your Json Object
    $scope.images = { 
   "data":[
     {"url":  "https://url1.com","code":"3cs14vs4"},
     {"url":  "https://url2.com","code":"512631va"}
   ],
}  
    
    
    
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">  
  
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="image in images.data" >
    <a ng-href="{{ image.code }}"><img ng-src="{{ image.url }}" ></a>
</li>
</ul>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note: Had changed your object data structure.*

Comment: Thank you for helping me , I appreciate it . Right now i am trying to change data structure in PHP.

Comment: Okay!! Welcome :)